# Django_filters - ModelChoiceFilter - How to filter based on the page_ID the user is visiting

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-filter

I would like the user to be able to filter based on categories. I am using `django_filters`.

Two important things:

1. These categories are not hard coded in the model. They are instead provided by `Venue`. `Venue` is the user the categories are displayed to.
2. I only want to show the categories relevant to the Venue ID page.

I am probably lacking a bit of "vocabulary" to express this in a way django understand.

It's a recurring problem I have, and somehow always manage to go around it. I think this time I am definitely going to need to do something about it. Would be useful to find out!

**model**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

    class Venue(models.Model, HitCountMixin):
        id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
        name = models.CharField(verbose_name="Name",max_length=100, 
    
    class Catalogue(models.Model):
        product = models.ManyToManyField('Product', blank=True)
        product_title = models.TextField('Product Title', blank=True) 
        venue = models.ForeignKey(Venue, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

**url**

```
path('show_venue/<venue_id>', views.show_venue,name="show-venue"),
```

**views**

```
def show_venue(request, venue_id):       

    if request.method == "POST" and 'btnreview_form' in request.POST:
        form = CatalogueReviewForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            data = form.save(commit=False)
            data.product_id = venue_id # links to product ID in Catalogue Model and return product name
            data.venue_id = request.POST.get('venue_id') # prints venue ID in form
            data.user_id = request.user.id
            data.save()
            ven_id = request.POST.get('venue_id')
            print(data)
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(ven_id)
    else:
        venue = Venue.objects.get(pk=venue_id)
        menu = Catalogue.objects.filter(venue=venue_id)
        categories = Catalogue.objects.filter(venue=venue_id).order_by('category_order')
        myFilter = CatalogueFilter(request.GET,queryset=categories)
        categories = myFilter.qs
```

**filter.py** This is where the problem is.

```
def venue_id(request):
    venue = Venue.objects.get(pk=venue_id) #<-- This is obvioulsy not right, but this is how far I got.
    queryset = Catalogue.objects.filter(venue=venue)
    return queryset 
    

class CatalogueFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    product_title = django_filters.CharFilter(label='',lookup_expr='icontains',widget=forms.widgets.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder':'Long list! Type the name of your product here.'}))
    type = django_filters.ModelChoiceFilter(queryset = venue_id)
    
    class Meta:
        model = Catalogue
        fields = ['product_title','type']
```

Comment: Can you share the code relevant to Venuec(like the model, relation to Catalogue and User model), please?

Comment: All done. I added the Venue model and the relationship between Catalogue and Venue. Your request about user model made me think I might have made it confusing talking about user type. So I correct this in the initial question. Venues are not a user, I would not know how to qualify them other than stakeholder. The have a list of products allocated to their accounts which is uploaded through the admin panel. The actual user model has not relationship with `Venue`. I feel I am making this more confusing as I write. Hopefully you understoof :) (thanks for helping!)

Comment: its confusing though, you already filtered the queryset by vanue_id before passing to the django-filter, why do you want to filter again inside django-filter?

Comment: The `ModelChoiceFilter` is not filtering when I use the filter. I either call `Catalogue.objects.all` which will show all `Products` (due to the M2M rel.), or if I try to filter by venue (as per above without the function in filter.py I will get `'function' object has no attribute 'all'`. (thanks for sticking around!)

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand in Django it's all outstanding :) but the pk inside the `venue = Venue.objects.get(pk=venue_id)` instead of the pk, you should use the id, at least from what I understood in the code. That should get the object in the database that corresponds to the id. Being the code

```
venue = Venue.objects.get(id=venue_id)
```

Besides that, I don't see the venue_id being given to the function venue_id.
By the way, the function venue_id gets the object that corresponds to the x id and then gives that object to the queryset variable equivalent to the categories stored in the database. I think it's this sorry if I got anything wrong I haven't coded in Django for a long time

Comment: Going to check that tonight when I get home. Will keep you posted. (tahnks!)